# Conditional Iteration over a Pandas Dataframe using Function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, iteration

every month I get a dataframe , so every month I will have to do some adjusts to the dataframe, I would like to create a function for just apply it on every dataframe without create the code again.
I have for the first dataframe, called enero:

```
for i in range(0,len(enero)):
    if enero.loc[i,"VENDEDOR_CLIENTE"] == "ARTURO":
        enero.loc[i,"MARCA"]="MAQUILA PINTUCO"
    elif enero.loc[i,"PROVEEDOR"] == "PEPITO" and enero.loc[i,"VENDEDOR_CLIENTE"] != "ARTURO":
        enero.loc[i,"MARCA"]="PINTURAS"
```

For the second dataframe, called febrero:

```
for i in range(0,len(febrero)):
    if febrero.loc[i,"VENDEDOR_CLIENTE"] == "ARTURO":
        febrero.loc[i,"MARCA"]="MAQUILA PINTUCO"
    elif febrero.loc[i,"PROVEEDOR"] == "PEPITO" and febrero.loc[i,"VENDEDOR_CLIENTE"] != "ARTURO":
        febrero.loc[i,"MARCA"]="PINTURAS"
```

So, as not to repeat the code every month, I would like to create a function:

```
def ajustemarca(df,VENDEDOR_CLIENTE,MARCA,PROVEEDOR):
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        if df.loc[i,"VENDEDOR_CLIENTE"] == "ARTURO":
            df.loc[i,"MARCA"]="MAQUILA PINTUCO"
        elif df.loc[i,"PROVEEDOR"] == "PEPITO" and df.loc[i,"VENDEDOR_CLIENTE"] != "ARTURO":
            df.loc[i,"MARCA"]="PINTURAS"
    return df.loc[i,"MARCA"]
```

Then, I am calling the function:

```
enero.apply(ajustemarca)
febrero.apply(ajustemarca)
```

But, it does not work. How can I do this function?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "does not work"? It will be helpful to include the output of your code, or any error messages you receive.

Comment: Also, it looks like you need to adjust the indentation in your `if` and `elif` blocks of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share an answer that someone wrote here, but it was deleted :(

The answer was perfect and now the code work:

```
def ajustemarca(df):
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        if df.loc[i,"VENDEDOR_CLIENTE"] == "ARTURO":
            df.loc[i,"MARCA"]="MAQUILA PINTUCO"
        elif df.loc[i,"PROVEEDOR"] == "PEPITO." and df.loc[i,"VENDEDOR_CLIENTE"] != "ARTURO":
             df.loc[i,"MARCA"]="PINTURAS"
ajustemarca(enero)
ajustemarca(febrero)
```